# Sphinx-multiversion: Download file not readable

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have a Sphinx documentation and would like to have a multiversion Sphinx docs.

On top of that, I have a zip file which I would like to be part of the documentation, where visitors can just click and download.

I have the zip file in `./docs/source/_downloads/examples/` folder. In one of the RST file, the download link is annotated as:

```
:download:`here </_downloads/examples/examples.zip>`
```

However, I get this error when building the docs via `sphinx-multiversion "docs/source" "docs/build/html" -W --keep-going -n`:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpei93x8y0\6d1e6ca1fe60c272b003f0bf7e611df99dc35d1d\docs\source\examples.rst:4: WARNING: download file not readable: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpei93x8y0\6d1e6ca1fe60c272b003f0bf7e611df99dc35d1d\docs\source\_downloads\examples\examples.zip
```

I am using `Python 3.9.4`, `Sphinx 7.0.1` and `sphinx-multiversion 0.2.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently sphinx-multiversion archives the files via commit hashes, hence if the changes are made locally and not committed via `git commit`, the sphinx-multiversion build will fail.

In sphinx-multiversion's [git.py](https://github.com/Holzhaus/sphinx-multiversion/blob/cdc9cb591a738e67a5aacc458f9c95e2b88a94c2/sphinx_multiversion/git.py#L156) module:

```
def copy_tree(gitroot, src, dst, reference, sourcepath="."):
    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as fp:
        cmd = (
            "git",
            "archive",
            "--format",
            "tar",
            reference.commit,
            "--",
            sourcepath,
        )
        subprocess.check_call(cmd, cwd=gitroot, stdout=fp)
        fp.seek(0)
        with tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=fp) as tarfp:
            tarfp.extractall(dst)
```

Used in sphinx-multiversion's [main.py](https://github.com/Holzhaus/sphinx-multiversion/blob/cdc9cb591a738e67a5aacc458f9c95e2b88a94c2/sphinx_multiversion/main.py#L231):

```
git.copy_tree(str(gitroot), gitroot.as_uri(), repopath, gitref)
```

Once I `git add` and `git commit` the downloadable file, the build works perfectly without errors.